# need to create a Redis release, indicating that it generates 2 replicas

Tags: helm3

I am newbie in helm. I need help for get something like the image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt5J5.jpg

```
First I make this:
$ helm create mychart
$ I open mychart and open the file values.yaml in replicaCount I put 3
$ helm install my-release ./mychart/
```

But the problem I don't get the same like the image.
What I can do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer. Only I need put this:

```
$ helm install my-release bitnami/redis --set replica.replicaCount=2
```

Thank you!